# Spring boot with Flyway SQL script not effective

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

- FlyWay 8.5.13
- Spring Boot 2.7.4
- MySQL 8.0.30
- mysql-connector-java 8.0.30

This is my pom.xml file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my SQL script file : V2.0.0__add_table_user.sql

```
use `testflyway`;
CREATE TABLE `sys_user`
(
    `user_id`         int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username`        varchar(1024)    NOT NULL unique ,
    `encode_password` varchar(1024)       NOT NULL,
    `age`             int(3)           NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;

insert into  `testflyway`.`sys_user` values (1,'Felordcn','{noop}12345',18);
```

This is my spring boot yml configuration

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testFlyWay?useUnicode=true&useSSL=true&characterEncoding=utf8
    username: root
#    No password is set for the database
#    password: root123

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    clean-disabled: true
    clean-on-validation-error: false
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    table: flyway_schema_history
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    baseline-version: 1
    encoding: UTF-8
    out-of-order: false
    schemas: testflyway
    validate-on-migrate: true
```

when i start up my application my db only have one table named **flyway_schema_history**
and the sql script in my SQL file *V2.0.0__add_table_user.sql* not executed I'm very confused

I m sure my sql file at the right place
**src/main/resources/db/migration**

Comment: This looks fine. Can you try to remove all the flyway configuration?

Comment: What is your project structure like? In What folder/package does your `V2.0.0__add_table_user.sql` exist in?